# Browser.OpenAsync different behavior on APIs 33 and 32

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

I'm opening a twitter URL with the following code `await Browser.OpenAsync(twitterUrl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);` in a project that targets Android API 33.

When running this on the emulator **Android 13** opens the link in a **browser**. On the other hand **Android 12** opens it with the **Twitter app**.

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: In emulator / settings / apps / twitter / open supported links, does it say "open automatically"? (I don't know exact wording.) If you change to 'Always Ask", does the "disambiguation dialog" come up when app opens URL? It should.

Comment: Is Twitter installed on the emulator that runs Android 13?

Comment: @ewerspej You are right. It isn't... Yet what I would expect is that Browser.OpenAsync would open the browser in Android 12 and not the Twitter app. Launcher.OpenAsync is supposed to launch the app, right?

Comment: It depends on the installed app and the user's choice how the link is opened. Maybe this helps: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/ Also, what exactly is the problem then? Instead of asking whether something is expected behavior you should maybe rephrase your question and describe your expectation.

Comment: So is there any substantial difference between using Browser.OpenAsync vs Launcher.OpenAsync?

Comment: Yes, `Launcher.OpenAsync()` should be used to open URIs with an app, e.g. for deep linking. `Browser.OpenAsync()` will always attempt to open a browser based on the launch mode, AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can check the `settings / apps / twitter / Open by default`, does it open? If it does you can close it, then you can open the twitter in the Browser.

Second, the `await Launcher.OpenAsync(twitterUrl);` method open the Url in the chrome and the  `await Browser.OpenAsync(twitterUrl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);` method open the Url in the app by using a webview powered by chrome.

Comment: I checked `settings / apps / twitter / Open by default`. Indeed `Open Supported links` is enabled for the Twitter app, so I guess that's the answer in my question.